Trying to get the client ipaddress using Jacorb transport current throws org.jacorb.transport.current - No events were available
I have tried to start the Jacorb orb with the transport current properties set in my service controller.
but by adding these properties throws exceptions while starting each of my services on my application code saying.
2024/04/30 19:14:27 | [WrapperSimpleAppMain] ERROR org.jacorb.transport.current - No events were available. Is traits() called outside of an upcall or interceptor?
2024/04/30 19:14:27 | [WrapperSimpleAppMain] ERROR org.jacorb.transport.current - No events were available. Is traits() called outside of an upcall or interceptor?
2024/04/30 19:14:27 |  2024-04-30 19:14:27:934 Starting service-> LicenseManager:0 [1255953242]

Can someone share any hints on how to get rid of these exceptions or fix them?
Tried adding the Jacorb properties to my Service controller.
